# How to retrieve array field from "User" table and get records from other table? parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, relation

I have 3 tables on parse

- User table - has users and lists they follow
- List table - has user created list
- Message table - pointers to record from List table

A user may follow multiple list, so all the list id's are stored as array of object id's corresponding to records in list table

When I call

```
NSArray *convArr = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"lists"];
```

it shows there is list object, but it looks as if empty and I cannot retrieve values from it to further query list table to get the lists user is following

```
For all the users and their list I have 


PFQuery *uQuery = [PFUser query];
[uQuery includeKey:@"lists"];
[uQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    ...
}];
```

but I can't pass current user information in the query.

```
[uQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]]; or
[uQuery includeKey:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
```

Adding any of this doesn't pull up records for the current user.

Comment: Wait are you saving an `array` of `PFObjects`?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into Relational Queries of Parse.com. (https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-relational/iOS).

Comment: I did it already @BartdeRuijter, but forgot to put it in the OP, I am improving with every question I ask to help people not send me links which could be most obvious thing to do before coming to StackOverflow for help.

Comment: My problem is that I've managed to solve this issue in Android programming but I cannot accomplish the same in iOS due to lack of my experience with it. Regardless both languages are build upon the same principle. Therefore I was hoping that any insight in the how-to from the docs could provide some help for you

Answer (score 0):

You could try refreshing the current user so the latest data is pulled from the server, and then looking at the lists object.

```
[[PFUser currentUser] fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *user, NSError *error){
  NSArray *convArr = [user objectForKey:@"lists"];
}];
```

Comment: Throws error: object not found for get (Code: 101, Version: 1.6.3)

Comment: I have done:

    PFQuery *uQuery = [PFUser query];
    [uQuery includeKey:@"lists"];
    [uQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) return;
        NSLog(@"Obj: %@",objects);
    }];

this gives me all the records for all users and if I add

    [uQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

this returns no result

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm going to try it anyhow.

I'm going to assume you have a currentUser you want to retrieve all their lists for. You could do a simple query like this (Ofcourse assuming you have an array with objectIds of the lists he made):

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"List"];
[query whereKey:@"objectId" containedIn:currentUser[@"lists"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *lists, NSError *error) {
    //This should return all the lists based on the keys inside the column of lists from the current User
}
```

If you want to do this for every User you'd have to query the user first, then basically do the same thing but instead of user "currentUser[@"lists"]", you'd use something similar like "queriedUser[@"lists"]". Pardon me in advance for the horrible syntax.

Also one handy tool for finding the right "querying constraints" might be this [link](http://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html)

I hope this atleast has helped you a bit!